# Can the word "doping" refer to controlling the Fermi energy via a gate field?

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-hall-effect

In the Integer Quantum Hall Effect with a fixed value of the perpendicular magnetic field, I believe that the filling factor $\nu$ which determines the Hall conductivity is experimentally controlled by a gate field (which controls the Fermi energy). Is this correct?

My question: is it correct to refer to the process of adding electrons to this system via changing the gate field, as a process of doping? My understanding is that doping refers to the introduction of impurity atoms to the material.

I'm asking this question because I'm trying to read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.04813), and I'm not sure what is meant when the word doping is used.

Comment: Why not? This usage is not uncommon. Google "electric field doping" for example.